# Directory Website - Use JS array to alphabetize then display in separate divs

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, json, directory

I am trying to replace a directory website that we currently use Wix for. Whenever we have to add or remove a staff member it's a nightmare to re-sort/alphabetize the whole site manually.

What I am hoping to do is store everything in a JS/Json file like this:

```
var staffData = '[
  {
    "FirstName":"Alexis",
    "LastName":"Gannnnn",  
    "departmentName":"department",
    "positionName":"Graphic Designer",
    "locationName":"209G",
    "phoneNumber":"111-111-1111",
    "emailAddress":"first.last@uni.edu",
    "profilePicture" : "https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/60/03/61/360_F_260036118_AUYppgsODQeTCnbu0OXGNDXB8EVzpxKq.jpg"
  },
  {
    "FirstName":"Erin",
    "LastName":"Rannnn",  
    "departmentName":"department",
    "positionName":"Admin and Comm Manager",
    "locationName":"remote",
    "phoneNumber":"111-111-1111",
    "emailAddress":"first.last@uni.edu",
    "profilePicture" : "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/pretty-smiling-joyfully-female-fair-260nw-776697943.jpg"
  },
  {
    "FirstName":"Brady",
    "LastName":"Bonnnn",  
    "departmentName":"department",
    "positionName":"Coordinator",
    "locationName":"209G",
    "phoneNumber":"111-111-1111",
    "emailAddress":"first.last@uni.edu",
    "profilePicture" : "https://images.stockfreeimages.com/2112/sfi226w/21126966.jpg"
  },
  {
    "FirstName":"Jeniffer",
    "LastName":"Linnnn",  
    "departmentName":"department",
    "positionName":"Coordinator",
    "locationName":"remote",
    "phoneNumber":"111-111-1111",
    "emailAddress":"first.last@uni.edu",
    "profilePicture" : "https://s3.envato.com/files/338574216/2655.jpg"
  }
]';
```

I then want to output it into something that looks like this:

[image: directory mockup]

It's been a minute since I have worked in JS/Json so I am a little rusty.

But my biggest primary objective is to:

- have it alphabetize by first name.
- Display like in the photo (not in a table format).

The only other thing is that there is 50+ staff members and it needs to only display 6 at a time, and then will carousel scroll through it.

thank you in advance! any kind of advice or direction/resource would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this via using [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method and for the display cards you can use grid layout.

**Working Demo :**

```js
var staffData = [{
  "FirstName":"Alexis",
  "LastName":"Gannnnn",  
  "departmentName":"department",
  "positionName":"Graphic Designer",
  "locationName":"209G",
  "phoneNumber":"111-111-1111",
  "emailAddress":"first.last@uni.edu",
  "profilePicture" : "https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/60/03/61/360_F_260036118_AUYppgsODQeTCnbu0OXGNDXB8EVzpxKq.jpg"
}, {
  "FirstName":"Erin",
  "LastName":"Rannnn",  
  "departmentName":"department",
  "positionName":"Admin and Comm Manager",
  "locationName":"remote",
  "phoneNumber":"111-111-1111",
  "emailAddress":"first.last@uni.edu",
  "profilePicture" : "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/pretty-smiling-joyfully-female-fair-260nw-776697943.jpg"
}, {
  "FirstName":"Brady",
  "LastName":"Bonnnn",  
  "departmentName":"department",
  "positionName":"Coordinator",
  "locationName":"209G",
  "phoneNumber":"111-111-1111",
  "emailAddress":"first.last@uni.edu",
  "profilePicture" : "https://images.stockfreeimages.com/2112/sfi226w/21126966.jpg"
}, {
  "FirstName":"Jeniffer",
  "LastName":"Linnnn",  
  "departmentName":"department",
  "positionName":"Coordinator",
  "locationName":"remote",
  "phoneNumber":"111-111-1111",
  "emailAddress":"first.last@uni.edu",
  "profilePicture" : "https://s3.envato.com/files/338574216/2655.jpg"
}];

// Sorting the staffData objects by FirstName in ascending order.
staffData.sort((a, b) => a.FirstName.toLowerCase() > b.FirstName.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1);

['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'].forEach((elem, index) => {
    document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML = staffData[index].FirstName + '</br>' + staffData[index].departmentName + ' | ' + staffData[index].positionName 
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
}
.card {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card" id="one"></div>
  <div class="card" id="two"></div>
  <div class="card" id="three"></div>
  <div class="card" id="four"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach to sort your array alphabetic by `FirstName`.

```js
var staffData = [{
    "FirstName": "Alexis",
    "LastName": "Gannnnn",
    "departmentName": "department",
    "positionName": "Graphic Designer",
    "locationName": "209G",
    "phoneNumber": "111-111-1111",
    "emailAddress": "first.last@uni.edu",
    "profilePicture": "https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/60/03/61/360_F_260036118_AUYppgsODQeTCnbu0OXGNDXB8EVzpxKq.jpg"
  },
  {
    "FirstName": "Erin",
    "LastName": "Rannnn",
    "departmentName": "department",
    "positionName": "Admin and Comm Manager",
    "locationName": "remote",
    "phoneNumber": "111-111-1111",
    "emailAddress": "first.last@uni.edu",
    "profilePicture": "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/pretty-smiling-joyfully-female-fair-260nw-776697943.jpg"
  },
  {
    "FirstName": "Brady",
    "LastName": "Bonnnn",
    "departmentName": "department",
    "positionName": "Coordinator",
    "locationName": "209G",
    "phoneNumber": "111-111-1111",
    "emailAddress": "first.last@uni.edu",
    "profilePicture": "https://images.stockfreeimages.com/2112/sfi226w/21126966.jpg"
  },
  {
    "FirstName": "Jeniffer",
    "LastName": "Linnnn",
    "departmentName": "department",
    "positionName": "Coordinator",
    "locationName": "remote",
    "phoneNumber": "111-111-1111",
    "emailAddress": "first.last@uni.edu",
    "profilePicture": "https://s3.envato.com/files/338574216/2655.jpg"
  }
];

console.log(staffData.sort((a, b) => {
  var nameA = a.FirstName.toLowerCase(),
    nameB = b.FirstName.toLowerCase();
  if (nameA < nameB) //sort string ascending
    return -1;
  if (nameA > nameB)
    return 1;
  return 0; //default return value (no sorting)
}));
```

To make the layout you can use Grid Layouts ([here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) or [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)) and there are many tutorials how to make a carousel.